# iPhone died while recording audio, how do I retrieve it?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-recovery

Is there a way to recover the recorded audio file while the phone died. When I recharged the phone and looked in the Voice Recording app, it shows the recording listed but with 00:00 recording time. I'm not sure if the audio file is still somewhere on the phone, and not sure how to recover it